# Flutter Button Placed below GridView Builder

Tags: flutter, gridview

I want to have a big long button below the Gridview just like the logout button in the Roblox app

[image]

I manage to create a gridview and button using the Column , however the button is floating above the gridview, how to make it placed nicely below the gridview without floating above the gridview?

Here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Grid List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: MainMenuBody(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainMenuBody extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final List<MenuData> menu = [
      MenuData(Icons.move_to_inbox_outlined, 'Menu 1'),
      MenuData(Icons.find_in_page_outlined, 'Menu 2'),
      MenuData(Icons.find_in_page_outlined, 'Menu 3'),
      MenuData(Icons.upgrade_outlined, 'Menu 4'),
      MenuData(Icons.upgrade_outlined, 'Menu 5'),
      MenuData(Icons.play_for_work_outlined, 'Menu 6'),
      MenuData(Icons.play_for_work_outlined, 'Menu 7'),
      MenuData(Icons.assignment_turned_in_outlined, 'Menu 8'),
      MenuData(Icons.assignment_turned_in_outlined, 'Menu 9'),
      MenuData(Icons.fact_check_outlined, 'Menu 10')
    ];

    return Container(
    child: Scrollbar(
  thickness: 3,
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: menu.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                childAspectRatio: 1,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Card(
                elevation: 0.2,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        menu[index].icon,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Text(
                        menu[index].title,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: Colors.black87),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Button"),
              onPressed: (){},
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
));
  }
}

class MenuData {
  MenuData(this.icon, this.title);
  final IconData icon;
  final String title;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have modified your code a little bit. Please have a look.

Wrap the column inside a `SingleChildScrollView`, Remove `Expanded` widget and add `shrinkWrap: true` inside `GridView`

```
return Container(
    child: Scrollbar(
  thickness: 3,
  child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: menu.length,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                childAspectRatio: 1,
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Card(
                elevation: 0.2,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        menu[index].icon,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Text(
                        menu[index].title,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: Colors.black87),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Button"),
              onPressed: (){},
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
));
```

Comment: This work, but the physics: BouncingScrollPhysics() this effect is gone, how to enable back?

Comment: remove physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(), from GridView and add it inside SingleChildScrollView. I hope this will work

Comment: have test not work, need to put physics: BouncingScrollPhysics() in both gridview and singlechildscrollview then can work , Not sure what is the logic behind

Answer (score 1):

Update: Not sure if this is in general the way to go, but you could create a scrollview wrapping the column wrapping gridview and the button. In grid view you then have to disable scrolling with `physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

But maybe columns and rows are the way to go for this

Comment: Have try but still the same, it occupies the bottom space

Comment: sorry, got your question wrong. see updated answer

Comment: when set the NeverScrollableScrollPhysics, the button still occupy the bottom space, it wont go below the last item of gridview

Comment: have you correctly embedded the column into the SingleChildScrollView? See here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html However, as this becomes a bit unclear, using ListView with Rows or SingleChildScrollView with Rows and Columns may provide a cleaner code

Comment: ok, how to enable BouncingScrollPhysics() on SingleChildScrollView ?

Comment: I guess by adding this with `physics: ... ` to the SingleChildScrollView